# Promises in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I'm new to angular, i m going through the angular-tour-of-heroes app,where im not able to understand the promises concept here in getHeroes method.
Can anyone please explain?

Here is the service.ts

```
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
```

Here is the component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of heroes';
 heroes:Hero[];
 selectedHero:Hero;
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
ngOnInit() {
   this.getHeroes();
  }

 onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a dummy implementation of `getHeroes` that returns a promise of constant values. In reality this would be an ajax request.

Comment: It just returns `HEROES` as `Promise`, like it would if you'd make a real request to a server. When you use `Http`, it will actually be an `Observable`, but it still demonstrates the basics of async execution.

Comment: Thanks! can you also explain what the .then inside getHeroes method does?